# Accessing localhost not possible on MacOS

Tags: django, localhost

my situation is that the website I'm building has a landing page the main App page and the API section. They are respectively reachable with `[domain_name]`, `app.[domain_name]` and `api.[domain_name]`. When calling those I don't have any problems reaching them in any browser. When I host them however in my local environment then `api.localhost` does only work when I call it with Postman.

When I try to ping the `api.localhost` it only says:

```
ping: cannot resolve api.localhost: Unknown host
```

On other systems, this will get a response.

In terms of Django Cors stuff, it all seems to be managed correctly as it is working on other systems. But I can add any code if asked for such, just don't want to add everything that I can think of from the Django project.

And information about my System MacOS 10.15.3, Django 2.1.5

I have no idea what to try or what to change so any help would be beneficial.

Comment: have you added api.localhost in /etc/hosts?

Comment: @AndreyNelubin Thanks, yup solved the problem. Didn't think that the problem was in there as it did work at some prior point. Regardless it works now.